# How to use setup_class to define a variable to be accessed in all methods of class

Tags: python, pytest

I need to define a variable in a fixture method setup_class for pytest like

```
class testClassForPytest:
  @classmethod
  def setup_class(cls):
    m = aClassInstance(classInput)

  def test_case_1(self):
    #use of the instance m with a method of its class
```

I tried above approach but wasn't able to use the instance m.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the setting up of test suite (the class) for pytest is inherited from the standard python library unittest. With that library, the method is called `setUpClass` and should probably call the same method on its parent class. However since you are using pytest, which doesn't seem to follow the idea of test suites, I'm not entirely sure this is a problem. Still, it might be one source of problems if the method is supposed to be called something else.

In your code the method `setup_class`, you set a variable `m` to a value, but this variable is restricted to the local scope of the method. Only if you previously defined the variable on the scope of the class, or if you explicitly reference the variable in the class scope, can you later access the value again.

For example you could simply move the declaration into the class scope:

```py
class testClassForPytest:
  m = aClassInstance(classInput) 

  def test_case_1(self):
    #use of the instance m with a method of its class
```

In this case you don't the setup method at all. If you need specific inputs that are not available on class declaration, you can also set the variable directly:

```py
  @classmethod
  def setup_class(cls):
    cls.m = aClassInstance(classInput)
```

Comment: It is specifically required to use the setup_class ficture

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you meant, that in `setup_class` you meant to do `cls.m = aClassInstance(classInput)`, not just `m = ...`

for that, you could modify your code to use pytest's class scope fixture to achieve the same result:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup_class(request):
  m = aClassInstance(classInput)
  request.cls.m = m # makes pytest to add created instance to class to which fixture is applied to

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_class")
class testClassForPytest:
  def test_case_1(self):
    #use of the instance m as self.m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test_visualization:

    data: int = 0

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self):
        self.data = 3

    @classmethod    
    def setup_class(cls):
        Test_visualization.data = 3
```

> `setup_class` Class will run only onces inside class

> `setup` will run for every test creating a new instance of the class

From [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/getting-started.html#getstarted) its written

> `Something to be aware of when grouping tests inside classes is that each test has a unique instance of the class. Having each test share the same class instance would be very detrimental to test isolation and would promote poor test practices`

So it is better to define class variables that are common across all tests and instance variables that are created every time for a test

> Example for Pytest auto use Fixture

[Pytest Fixture Documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixtures)

[image: Pytest Autouse Fixture]